# Why is my behavioursubject subscription only firing once?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

In an Ionic - angular project, I have a service that starts a behaviour subject publicly in a service called FrequencyAnalyzer.

```
//Somewhere In models.ts
export interface tuneInfo{
    note:string,
    db: number,
    detectedFrequency:number,
    detectedKey: number,
    key? : Key
}

public processedTune = new BehaviorSubject<tuneInfo | undefined>(undefined);
```

Somewhere in this service. I use the "next" function to update the value of the behaviour subject.

```
 this.processedTune.next({
        note: this.note,
        db: maxValueInBuffer,
        detectedFrequency: ac,
        detectedKey : this.getKeyNumber(ac),
        key: this.key
      });
```

Then. In one of my pages. I subscribe to processedTune

```
this.frequencyAnalyzer.processedTune.subscribe(
      processedTune => {
        //console.log(`db: ${processedTune && processedTune.db}`);
        this.currentInfo = {
          note: processedTune && processedTune.note || '-',
          db: processedTune && processedTune.db || 0,
          detectedFrequency: processedTune && processedTune.detectedFrequency || 0,
          detectedKey: processedTune && processedTune.detectedKey || 0
        };
      }
    );
```

this.currentInfo is then passed along on to a child component

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    //things are done with the changes and everything is done properly in this part of the key

    }
```

Up to this point, everything is working pretty fine. Excellent. So Now I create a new service and in that service I am subscribing to the processedTune behavioursubject of the Frequency Analyzer in the same way that I am connecting  from the page

```
 public startSubscription(){
    this.frequencyAnalyzer.processedTune.subscribe(
      (processedTune => {
        console.log("Tune received: ", processedTune);
        //console.log(`db: ${processedTune && processedTune.db}`);
        this.currentInfo = {
          note: processedTune && processedTune.note || '-',
          db: processedTune && processedTune.db || 0,
          detectedFrequency: processedTune && processedTune.detectedFrequency || 0,
          detectedKey: processedTune && processedTune.detectedKey || 0,
          key: processedTune && processedTune.key
        };
         //do more stuff.
        
      }).bind(this));
  }
```

However. No matter how many changes are happening in the behaviour subject, and that the first subscription is detecting, this Service is only detecting the first initial status (undefined). It is not firing for any of the other changes, despite the fact that the other subscription is working perfectly.

I have tried calling startSubscription() from the service constructor, from the page... and I've also tried setting undefined to some static variable in the form of :
public processedTune = new BehaviorSubject<tuneInfo | undefined>({dbDetected:0, ..... }); (Following the interface specs) but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong? Is the first subscription doing something to the second subscription? I know angular is lazy but I thought behavioursubjects were able to multicast to different subscriptions. I feel like there's something I'm not completely understanding.

For more advanced Information. In my APP MODULE TS

```
 import { ALL_PROVIDERS } from './providers';
```

And then providers/index.ts is as follows

```
import { BluetoothService } from './bluetooth/bluetooth.service';
import { FrequencyAnalyzerService } from './frequency-analyzer/frequency-analyzer.service';
import { KeyboardService } from './keyboard/keyboard.service';
import { TunerControllerService } from './tuner-controller/tuner-controller.service';
import { SettingsService} from './settings/settings.service';

export * from './bluetooth/bluetooth.service';
export * from './frequency-analyzer/frequency-analyzer.service';
export * from './keyboard/keyboard.service';
export * from './tuner-controller/tuner-controller.service';
export * from './settings/settings.service';

export const ALL_PROVIDERS = [
  BluetoothService,
  FrequencyAnalyzerService,
  KeyboardService,
  TunerControllerService,
  SettingsService
];
```

I just realized there is no module.ts in each of the providers. And I reuse providers oftenly. Do providers require having a module.ts too?

[image]

Comment: How frequencyAnalyzer instance is provide to the other service? Are they in same module? Maybe you have two instances of Frequency Analyzer, and consequently, two different instances of the Behavior Subject

Comment: Hi Thiago. Everything is loaded in app.module.ts
Then. I have both services in app/providers folder

In app.module.ts I call:
import { ALL_PROVIDERS } from './providers';

Comment: Is your service also provided in root? Then Thiago is probably right, because you do not need to set it as provider if it is already in root. (which is the recommended way to provide a service if there is no specific reason to provide it in a specific Module only). Try removing the ALL_PROVIDERS Import and check what happens.

Comment: I managed to finally fix this Thiago. you certainly pointed me in the right direction, thanks.